# Show a hierarchical terms list Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to output a hierarchical terms list in my WP site (for Jquery Istotope). For some reason, its only showing the top level categories, how can I show all categories in hierarchical order?

```
<?php
    $terms = get_terms('industry');
    $count = count($terms);
    echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" data-filter=".all" class="active">View All</a></li>';
        if ( $count > 0 ){
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="'.$termname.'" data-filter=".'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
            }
         }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add second argument in `get_terms` function as below.

```
<?php
    $terms = get_terms('industry',array('parent'=>0,'orderby'=>'slug','hide_empty'=>false));
    $count = count($terms);
    echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" data-filter=".all" class="active">View All</a></li>';
    if ( $count > 0 ){
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $termname = strtolower($term->name);
        $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
        echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="'.$termname.'" data-filter=".'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
        }
     }
?>
```